# Can't access navigation props

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm trying to navigate using my custom NavBar component, which forces me to use navigation props. The issue is I'm getting errors that my navigation props are undefined. Right now I'm defining my nested navigators (result of one of my attempts) like that:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import SearchScreen from "./screens/SearchScreen";
import StatsScreen from "./screens/StatsScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./screens/ProfileScreen";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import StaticTabbar from "./components/StaticNavBar";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "react-native-screens/native-stack";
import { enableScreens } from "react-native-screens";

enableScreens();

function TabStack() {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{ tabBarVisible: false }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Search"
        component={SearchScreen}
        options={{ tabBarVisible: false }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Stats"
        component={StatsScreen}
        options={{ tabBarVisible: false }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{ tabBarVisible: false }}
      />

      <Tab.Screen
        name="NavBar"
        component={NavBar}
        options={{ tabBarVisible: false }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="StaticNav"
        component={StaticTabbar}
        options={{ tabBarVisible: false }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
function RootStack() {
  const Root = createNativeStackNavigator();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Root.Navigator>
        <Root.Screen
          name="First"
          component={TabStack}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Root.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const App = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <RootStack />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <NavBar navigation={props.navigation} />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    zIndex: 100,
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0
  }
});

export default App;
```

I marked both NavBar and StaticTabbar as routes to have access to navigation props from them, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried passing it manually since component where navigation is defined should be able to access it, but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your App in a `withRouter` HoC or you update to React > 16.8 and switch to the useLocation hooks. Additionally you can only access `props.navigation` inside the `RootStack`.

Comment: If they are nested then props should be accessible from both of them, right? Additionally you mean redux withRouter or sth else?

Comment: exactly! Just nest your `NavBar` in the `RootStack`